# Problems with linking CEF3

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking, chromium-embedded

I'm having some problems with using CEF in my application which uses the MD/MDd runtime library linking.

I have downloaded the latest build of CEF3 from [cefbuilds.com](http://cefbuilds.com/) and followed the instructions [How to link CEF against a different run-time library](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/LinkingDifferentRunTimeLibraries).

I have built the "libcef_dll_wrapper" project after changing "Runtime Library" to "/MDd" and "Platform Toolset" to "v110" and then I've linked the resulting "libcef_dll_wrapper.lib" binary to my project.

However, when I try to build my project I get the following errors:

```
12>html.lib(html_producer.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cef_string_utf16_clear referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl CefBrowserSettingsTraits::clear(struct _cef_browser_settings_t *)" (?clear@CefBrowserSettingsTraits@@SAXPAU_cef_browser_settings_t@@@Z)
12>html.lib(html_producer.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cef_string_utf8_to_utf16 referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl CefStringTraitsUTF16::from_string(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,struct _cef_string_utf16_t *)" (?from_string@CefStringTraitsUTF16@@SA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PAU_cef_string_utf16_t@@@Z)
12>html.lib(html_producer.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cef_string_list_free referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl CefSettingsTraits::clear(struct _cef_settings_t *)" (?clear@CefSettingsTraits@@SAXPAU_cef_settings_t@@@Z)
12>html.lib(html_producer.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static bool __cdecl CefBrowser::CreateBrowser(class CefWindowInfo &,class CefRefPtr<class CefClient>,class CefStringBase<struct CefStringTraitsUTF16> const &,class CefStructBase<struct CefBrowserSettingsTraits> const &)" (?CreateBrowser@CefBrowser@@SA_NAAVCefWindowInfo@@V?$CefRefPtr@VCefClient@@@@ABV?$CefStringBase@UCefStringTraitsUTF16@@@@ABV?$CefStructBase@UCefBrowserSettingsTraits@@@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall caspar::html::html_producer::run(void)" (?run@html_producer@html@caspar@@QAEXXZ)
12>html.lib(html_producer.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl CefInitialize(class CefStructBase<struct CefSettingsTraits> const &,class CefRefPtr<class CefApp>)" (?CefInitialize@@YA_NABV?$CefStructBase@UCefSettingsTraits@@@@V?$CefRefPtr@VCefApp@@@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall caspar::html::html_producer::run(void)" (?run@html_producer@html@caspar@@QAEXXZ)
12>libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(libcef_dll_wrapper.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cef_execute_process referenced in function "int __cdecl CefExecuteProcess(class CefMainArgs const &,class CefRefPtr<class CefApp>)" (?CefExecuteProcess@@YAHABVCefMainArgs@@V?$CefRefPtr@VCefApp@@@@@Z)
12>libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(libcef_dll_wrapper.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cef_initialize referenced in function "bool __cdecl CefInitialize(class CefMainArgs const &,class CefStructBase<struct CefSettingsTraits> const &,class CefRefPtr<class CefApp>)" (?CefInitialize@@YA_NABVCefMainArgs@@ABV?$CefStructBase@UCefSettingsTraits@@@@V?$CefRefPtr@VCefApp@@@@@Z)
12>libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(libcef_dll_wrapper.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cef_shutdown referenced in function "void __cdecl CefShutdown(void)" (?CefShutdown@@YAXXZ)
12>libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(libcef_dll_wrapper.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cef_do_message_loop_work referenced in function "void __cdecl CefDoMessageLoopWork(void)" (?CefDoMessageLoopWork@@YAXXZ)
12>libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(libcef_dll_wrapper.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cef_run_message_loop referenced in function "void __cdecl CefRunMessageLoop(void)" (?CefRunMessageLoop@@YAXXZ)
```

The full log can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/ronag/d83844149dde7e6b37e8).

Any ideas as to what I might be missing?

Answer (score 4):

Are you also libcef.lib in the linker input?

Comment: Probalby should have put that in the comments section

Comment: Correct, however my rep is too low to comment